# Generic type subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
public class Evalutor<T>{

}
```

I would like to create the type called NumberEvalutor as follows:

```
public class NumberEvalutor<T> extends Evalutor<T extends Number>{ //Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

}
```

But I couldn't do it that way. Maybe you can advice another type-safe way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with:

```
public class NumberEvalutor<T extends Number> extends Evalutor<T> { 

}
```

Type parameters on class-level (like `<T extends Number>`) must be introduced after the class name and can be referred in the super-class/super-interface list. Otherwise, there won't be a way to (explicitly) specify their runtime value when creating class instances.

Answer (score 4):

This one should work :)

```
public class NumberEvaluator<T extends Number> extends Evaluator<T> {
}
```